# Oyster mushrooms, inoculate log in summer, or wait for autumn?

Tags: mushrooms

I recently got some big logs, lime/linden.

I have oyster mushroom dowels, but it's summer in the UK and the logs are going to be drying out.

Should I wait for autumn and cool damp weather, or will that give other fungi an opportunity to take hold ?

Comment: How long have the logs been cut? If they are recent, from living trees, I would stack them somewhere off the ground until ready to use. One or two months should be fine to wait before inoculating fresh logs. more than a few months and you would risk other fungi taking hold. I've never heard of using Linden though - they do not grow where I live.

Comment: Thanks for replying. They were cut a couple of months ago. I stacked them in the shade in the yard. I did a  bit of searching and found that mushrooms will grow on linden, but they're not the first choice. But they're what I got so I'll see how it goes. I can soak the smaller ones in a rain barrel but the big ones will probably dry out more.

If anyone knows what grows best on linden please do tell.